# Encypting SMTP server password in Django Settings

Tags: django, encryption, smtp

I have a view that generates an email based on a form and sends it to three service vendors:

```
def quote(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    .
    .
    .
    send_mail(
    'Quote Request: ....',
    'Message Body',
    'myemail@email.com',
    ['vendor1@email.com, vendor2@email.com, vendor3@email.com]
    )
```

In my settings I have TLS, host, User, Password, and Port # number defined:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'stmp.office365.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@email.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'My Plain Text Password That I Want to Encrypt Here!'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

The process works great - but I need to encrypt that plain text password. What would be the best way to go about doing so?

Comment: Consider working with environment variables to keep information secret. This guide can help you: [Working with Environment Variables in Python](https://godjango.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem to do this, I mean people always now the origin password... an example; using function to doing encryption and return the original password to the new variable, of course people just print that variable to know the original password...

> But if you handle it with eg; form ***(to require typing the password before sending an email message)***, I think it possible... this what was in my head.

Django has a function to handle the password, it is [`make_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers)

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import hashers
>>> pwd = hashers.make_password('your-original-password')
>>> pwd
'pbkdf2_sha256$30000$74DtkZMARQHr$rC3CEdtDnDjRYE5U2ZRiWxuT+HQf3Aq1KTStpypZDV8='
>>>
```

Put this encoded password into your `settings.py`;

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pbkdf2_sha256$30000$74DtkZMARQHr$rC3CEdtDnDjRYE5U2ZRiWxuT+HQf3Aq1KTStpypZDV8='
```

And then, every time you need to send an email message, you require to typing the original password that you have, this condition to check your original password with [`hashers.check_password(password, encoded)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password)

This script below is an example how to do it;

**1. `forms.py`**

```
from django import forms

class QuoteForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    ....
```

**2. `views.py`**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import hashers
from django.conf import settings

from yourapp.forms import QuoteForm

ENCODED_PASSWORD = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD


def quote(request):
    template_name = 'yourtemplate.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            # in this section is important, 
            # so the password only known by it owner.
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            is_matched = hashers.check_password(password, ENCODED_PASSWORD)
            if is_matched:
                # change default encoded password from the settings,
                # with original password from field of `password`.
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = password

                send_mail(
                  subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                  ['vendor1@email.com, vendor2@email.com, vendor3@email.com]
                )
                return redirect('/success/page/')
            return redirect('/password-failed/page/')
        else:
            context = {'form': form, 'errors': form.errors}
            return render(request, template_name, context)
    else:
        form = QuoteForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

> I'm not sure this solution is better, because of course it difficult for users.